# Clearing variables in onDestroy() of a service, but not when Android restarts the service

Tags: android, android-service, ondestroy

I'm working on an app in which I stop and restart a service in my code. In the `onDestroy` function of the service, I am clearing some variables from Android's storage using SharedPreferences. However, I do not want this clearing to be done when Android restarts this service on its own (one such case is when I swipe off the activity from recent apps). In such a case, I would like to continue with the current variables.

Is there a way to figure out what exactly caused the `onDestroy` function to be called (whether it was done by Android or some other reason). I also have a hunch that my code design is not that great, I mean, it should be generic enough to not have to resort to such case-based execution. So if anyone has an alternate design for doing such a thing, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: "However, I do not want this clearing to be done when Android restarts this service on its own (one such case is when I swipe off the activity from recent apps). In such a case, I would like to continue with the current variables." -- in such a case, your process will be terminated, and therefore you do not have any "current variables" anymore. "if anyone has an alternate design for doing such a thing" -- simply do not do it. Or, at least explain why you think you need it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified. By "current variables" I meant the data which I have stored using SharedPreferences. This is stored in Android's storage and is accessible even after a service or acitivity has been destroyed. I think I'll edit the question to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid. It turns out that the `onDestroy` function isn't called whenever Android restarts the service, it's only called when the service is explicitly restarted/stopped.

Comment: No, onDestroy is "Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed."